# При каждом отступе показываются предложения nvim-cmp

Tags: регулярные-выражения, lua, vim

Я установил Neovim, расширения nvim-cmp и nvim-lspconfig, интегрировав его с clangd. Предложения показываются, все работает. Но, что бесит - это при каждом отступе всплывает окно с предложениями:

```
type function()
{
    | // | - курсор; на этом месте показывается окно с предложениями
}
```

Я подумал, что это из-за того, что nvim-cmp учитывает пробел как символ, поэтому пробовал решить эту проблему с помощью регулярного выражения `[^ \n][^ \n]`, но это ничего не дало. (expandtab включен, все табы заменяются пробелами). Вот сам конфиг (сокращенный вариант):

```
local cmp = require("cmp")
cmp.config(
{
    completion =
    {
        keyword_pattern = "[^ \n][^ \n]"
    }
})
```

В какую сторону копать?